# Laravel unique identifiers for latest foreign key in collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, uniqueidentifier

I have a Laravel collection with record IDs and foreign keys:

```
{id=1, foreign_id=1},
{id=2, foreign_id=1},
{id=3, foreign_id=2},
{id=4, foreign_id=3},
{id=5, foreign_id=2}
```

I expect:

```
{id=2, foreign_id=1},
{id=5, foreign_id=2},
{id=4, foreign_id=3}
```

I want to search Laravel query builder for unique values ​​for `foreign_id` if `id` in collection occurs more than 1 time.
I want then to give latest `foreign_id`.

Comment: How do you have this result ? can you post your query ? using `groupBy('foreign_id')` and `orderBy('foreign_id', 'DESC')` should be ok

Comment: I wrote more entries for example, but I only have currently 2 records:
`{id=820, dic_id=575}`
`{id=820, dic_id=577}`
After `$collection->groupBy('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')` returns 1 record, but `dic_id = 575` and I want the latest here

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to sort collection by "id" in descending order and than use unique method by "foreign_id"

```
$myCollection->sortByDesc('id')->unique('foreign_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$collection->unique('foreign_id');`

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm giving an example, You can check by yours,

```
$a = collect([
        [
            'id'         => 1,
            'foreign_id' => 2
        ],
        [
            'id'         => 2,
            'foreign_id' => 1
        ],
        [
            'id'         => 3,
            'foreign_id' => 2
        ],
        [
            'id'         => 4,
            'foreign_id' => 3
        ],
        [
            'id'         => 5,
            'foreign_id' => 2
        ],
    ]);
    $a->unique('foreign_id');
```

Comment: It doesn't work with my collection. In this case, it returns all 5 records

Comment: Can you share your snippets? I think something typo missing or check import class declaration.